# How do I put data in my Google spreadsheet using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api-js-client

I used this as reference https://github.com/ruucm/react-google-sheets
but i kept getting a gapi **404 error** whenever i would run this 
I have a hunch that the github link does not exists and therefore my app could not work

Or maybe I'm wrong.

Is there a really nice reference where I can send data from react js to google spreadsheets?

I've tried numerous attempts on spreadsheets but it does the opposite where in the spreadsheet will give data to the app
What I need is REACT TO SPREADSHEET

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactGoogleSheets from 'react-google-sheets';

class GoogleSheets extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            sheetLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <ReactGoogleSheets
                clientId={'243...apps.googleusercontent.com'}
                apiKey={'AIza...'}
                spreadsheetId={'2PAC...'}
                afterLoading={() => this.setState({ sheetLoaded: true })}
            >
                {this.state.sheetLoaded ?
                    <div>
                        {/* Access Data */}
                        {console.log('Your sheet data : ', this.props.getSheetsData( 'gSheets' ))}
                        {/* Update Data */}
                        <button onClick={() => {
                            this.props.updateCell(
                                'gSheets', // sheetName
                                'b', // column
                                2, // row
                                'TESTING', // value
                                null, // successCallback
                                (error) => {
                                    console.log('error', error)
                                } // errorCallback
                            );
                        }}>update cell!</button>
                    </div>
                    :
                    'loading...'
                }
            </ReactGoogleSheets>


        )

    }

}
export default GoogleSheets;
```

The output should be a button, with data inside it, to send it in the spreadsheet

but all I get is this error

> gapi.js:257 GET
>   [https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.ko.u0WhFdqJrXQ.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCO-v0Extr2gWwJAKxa0xtQS573uyA/cb=gapi.loaded_0](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.ko.u0WhFdqJrXQ.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCO-v0Extr2gWwJAKxa0xtQS573uyA/cb=gapi.loaded_0)
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Answer (score 1):

update `gapi.js` or update it "by hand" in your

```
node_modules/react-google-sheets/google-sheet-connector/gapi.js
```

and add the contents from https://apis.google.com/js/api.js.
Keep the last line where it says

```
module.exports = gapi;
```